# Why is my JavaScript link in my iframe not going to the link but instead refreshing the page with the iframe in the parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I have a lightbox with an iframe in it that is meant to direct users to a donation form. In the iframe, there are several suggested donation levels and one user entered amount, all of which are grabbed in the url so that when the user is brought over to the proper form, it's already filled in based off what they clicked on.

The pre-determined amounts are easy, and can simply be appended to the url to correspond to the level id and are appropriately loading the destination link in the parent window and selecting the correct donation amount. However, the user entered amount must be plugged in after the user has typed in their value, and hit 'donate'.

To accomplish this, I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


$("#calcAmt").click(function(){

var uamount = $("#userEnteredamount").val();
uamount = uamount.replace("$", "");
uamount = uamount.replace(".", "");


var donformuserurl = "http://baseurl.com/example1324.donation=form1&set.DonationLevel=11111&set.Value="

window.location = donformuserurl+uamount;

});
        });
</script>
```

And, in the head I'm using

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

To load any links into the parent window instead, and this works for my other donation levels.

But when the user clicks the donation button now, it instead reloads the iframe as the parent page, and from there the script works appropriately if the user enters the amount again and hits 'donate' again.

Why is this happening/ what can I do to fix it? I assume it must be something to do with the iframe, since it worked before it was iframed and currently works when it loads as the parent page.

Comment: Have you tried using `parent.location` instead of `window.location`?

Comment: I did now, and no go, I also tried `window.top.location.href`

Comment: Can you output `donformuserurl+uamount` in an alert or console.log to make sure the whole string is well formed?  Maybe your application is throwing a javascript error that's making the parent load in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your input, my problem ended up being something I didn't include here, which was that the div that triggered the onClick was set as an `<a>` with the `href="#"`. I changed it to a plain div and it routed correctly but stayed in the iframe, then used your suggestion of `parent.location` to great success.

Comment: Great! Just as an added note, whenever I use `#` in my `a` tags, I also include  `onclick="return false"`, so it doesn't follow the link on click.